# Arch Linux slow shutdown

Tags: arch-linux, shutdown

I'm suffering from a very slow shutdown/reboot with Arch Linux, so I followed the instructions given [here](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/#index2h1) to enable logging.

So [here](http://pastebin.com/xbkDsebW) is the log generated during (slow) reboot that unfortunatelly I can't analyze by myself. Can someone help me please to understand where the problem is?

PS: According to that article I've also tried rebooting with `sync && reboot -f` and it goes super fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a systemd bug that has been fixed in systemd-208-11. Arch is still at systemd-208-10 on my system.

See bug listed [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1023820).

See bug fixes listed [here.](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2014-0902/systemd-208-11.fc20)

Comment: Arch was still on 209-10 on my system too, so I build and installed systemd-git (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/systemd-git) from AUR but nothing changed (also after many reboot) :(

Answer (score 0):

Luca, it looks like you have a problem with your Avahi setup, it might be causing the delay in shutting down.

What I would do is compare the log you posted with the log if you do `sync && reboot -f` using `xxdiff` and see if that gives you an indication.